# Where to find latest release versions for official Android libraries?

Tags: android, gradle

For example:

- appcompat-v7
- play-services
- cardview-v7
- etc

The official documentation is apparently not updated automatically, for example:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Appcompat version 22.x is already available at time of writing.

Where can I keep myself up to date and track latest releases (major, minor, bugfixes) and its changelog.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can check http://android-developers.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of versions, the definitive answer of what versions are available to you is what is on your hard drive, assuming that you have the Android Repository and the Google Repository up to date via the SDK Manager. You will find those repositories at `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/` and `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/m2repository/`, respectively. These are Maven-style repositories, and version information is available on a per-artifact basis.

In terms of announcements, follow [the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/), where this stuff is (usually) announced. For example, here are the announcement posts related to the most recent updates to [the Android Support package](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) and [the Play Services SDK](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/theres-lot-to-explore-with-google-play.html).